Start windows service (topshelf) fails
I am trying to install and start a windows service in an azure vm but the start step is failing.
Here are the pipeline tasks:
- task: jabbera.windows-service-release-tasks.install-topshelf-service-task.InstallTopshelfService@8
  displayName: 'Install a Topshelf Service'
  inputs:
    TopshelfExePaths: '${{ parameters.svcDir}}\${{ parameters.svcAssemblyName }}.exe'
    specialUser: localsystem
    ServiceName: '${{ parameters.svcName}}'
    StartupType: autostart
    KillMmcTaskManager: true
    deploymentGroup: true


 - task: jabbera.windows-service-release-tasks.start-windows-service-task.StartWindowsService@8
   displayName: 'Start Windows Service'
   inputs:
       ServiceNames: '${{ parameters.svcName}}'
       deploymentGroup: true

Start fails with the following error:

##[error]Unable to find type [VstsTaskSdk.TerminationException].
2024-05-08T09:54:34.2331237Z ##[error]Exit code 1 returned from process: file name 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe', arguments '-NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -Non***nteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". ([scriptblock]::Create('if ([Console]::***nputEncoding -is [Text.UTF8Encoding] -and [Console]::***nputEncoding.GetPreamble().Length -ne 0) { [Console]::nputEncoding = New-Object Text.UTF8Encoding $false } if (!$PSHOME) { $null = Get-tem -LiteralPath ''variable:PSHOME'' } else { ***mport-Module -Name ([System.***O.Path]::Combine($PSHOME, ''Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management.psd1'')) ; ***mport-Module -Name ([System.***O.Path]::Combine($PSHOME, ''Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility.psd1'')) }')) 2>&1 | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose $_.Exception.Message -Verbose } ; mport-Module -Name 'C:\azagent\A1_work_tasks\StartWindowsService_bf65dd9d-18cb-40d9-9254-f3ac527428ef\8.0.0\ps_modules\VstsTaskSdk\VstsTaskSdk.psd1' -ArgumentList @{ Nonnteractive = $true } -ErrorAction Stop ; $VerbosePreference = 'SilentlyContinue' ; $DebugPreference = 'SilentlyContinue' ; ***nvoke-VstsTaskScript -ScriptBlock ([scriptblock]::Create('. ''C:\azagent\A1_work_tasks\StartWindowsService_bf65dd9d-18cb-40d9-9254-f3ac527428ef\8.0.0\StartWindowsService.ps1'''))"'.

Github link: https://github.com/jabbera/my-vsts-tasks
I tried replacing it with powershell task:
- powershell: |
    $serviceName = '${{ parameters.serviceName }}'
    $serviceStatus = Get-Service -Name $serviceName
    if ($serviceStatus.Status -eq 'Running') {
        Write-Host "Service '$serviceName' is already running."
    } elseif ($serviceStatus.Status -eq 'Stopped') {
        Start-Service -Name $serviceName
        Write-Host "Service '$serviceName' started successfully."
    } else {
        Write-Host "Service '$serviceName' is in an unexpected state: $($serviceStatus.Status)"
    }
  condition: ${{ parameters.startService }}
  displayName: 'Start Windows Service'

But this failed:

Start-Service : Service 'MyService' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot
2024-05-08T14:25:47.7248406Z start service MyService on computer '.'.
2024-05-08T14:25:47.7250339Z At C:\azagent\A1_work_temp\5d2155f7-3687-4ce8-ab8e-fbf42272de9d.ps1:9 char:5
2024-05-08T14:25:47.7252117Z +     Start-Service -Name $serviceName
2024-05-08T14:25:47.7253589Z +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2024-05-08T14:25:47.7255675Z     + Categorynfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service],
2024-05-08T14:25:47.7257458Z    ServiceCommandException
2024-05-08T14:25:47.7259190Z     + FullyQualifiedErrord : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
2024-05-08T14:25:47.7260730Z
2024-05-08T14:25:47.7300363Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2024-05-08T14:25:47.7904871Z ##[section]Finishing: Start Windows Service: MyService


From the logs you provided, you seem is using a self-hosted Windows agent to run the pipeline job.
You can check with the following things to fix the issue:

Use your account to log on the Windows machine where the self-hosted agent is installed.

Try to manually execute the related command to install and start the Topshelf service. If your account also cannot install and start the service,  it might need the Admin account to perform the actions.

Search for Services and open it. Find the running agent service. Right click to open its Properties. On the "Log On"tab, check whether the agent service is set to use the default Windows built-in account 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' to log on the machine. If so, this account might not have the permissions to install and start the service on the machine. You can try to configure the agent service to log on the machine with the Admin account, or your account if you have the permissions to perform the actions.




Thanks for your response. I logged into my account and tried to manually start: "Windows service error 1053: The service did not respond to start or control request in a timely fashion." Services Log On is set to Local System Account

@TrialByFire, Do your account and the Local System Account have the permissions to install and start services on the machine? Did you try an Admin account?

@TrialByFire, If you still gets errors when manually installing and starting the service with these local accounts, the problem might be with the Topshelf service or the machine itself.

Another service with similar set up goes fine it does give a  few log messages similar to this but still goes thorugh

@TrialByFire, Is the Another service also the Topshelf service? Did you use the same account to install and start it on the same machine?

Yes everything is exactly the same, please let me know if you would like me to share any details from that? Also I am trying a new task I found but that is also failing at the same point. New task: MDSolutions.WindowsServiceManagerWindowsServiceManager.WindowsServiceManager.WindowsServiceManager@4

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@TrialByFire, How did you manually download and install the Topshelf service on the machine? Did you use command script? If so, try to use the same script in pipeline, and also configure the agent service to log on with the same account that you manually log on the machine.

Sorry for delay, I have tried to update the log on tab details with providing details in This Account field. I have given the credentials I log on to the machine and a generic admin cred as well. Both end up with the same error: Windows service error 1053: The service did not respond to start or control request in a timely fashion

In event viewer: Faulting application name: SampleServiceHost.exe, version: 1.3.0.0, time stamp: 0x88bf0740
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.20348.2400, time stamp: 0x08763f47
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00139072
Faulting process id: 0x15d0
Faulting application start time: 0x01daa5e1bab50efe
Faulting application path: Service Dir Path\SampleServiceHost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: bc3f7bc1-5385-491c-babc-a3081b77ac90
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:

@TrialByFire, Can you check if there is any restriction policy set on the agent machine that may prevent the Topshelf service from being installing or starting?

But it should then also apply to other service which I again tried yesterday and worked

@TrialByFire, Do you have any local account can successfully install and start the Topshelf service when manually logging on the agent machine? If you need to use the Topshelf service often, you can manually install and start it on the agent machine and keep the service online, instead of using pipeline to install and start.

I will try that too... as of now I saw some event viewer logs that are pointing to a section in the code. I am trying to see if that can be rectified. I will also see if I find time to manually install the service

@TrialByFire, That's good. Go ahead to try it.
